# How to stop gdb from showing "New Thread" and "Thread exited"?

Tags: multithreading, gdb

Is there a way to tell gdb not to show messages of the form

```
[New Thread 0x7fffc8ff9700 (LWP 32104)]
[Thread 0x7fffc8ff9700 (LWP 32104) exited]
```

i Have to debug an application with millions of these messages which slow down everything -
i can't seem to get to the problematic code...

Answer (score 2):

```
(gdb) set print thread-events off
```

Documentation [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html).